# Descendant jQuery selector not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

I have two html `forms` as follows

```
<form action="#" id="saveForm" name="saveForm">
<input type="hidden" id="rname" name="rname" />
</form>

<form action="#" id="interactor" name="interactor">
<input type="hidden" id="rname" name="rname" />
</form>
```

I am trying to `alert` the id attribute of the **second** `form` `input` element using the following jQuery code

**Snippet 1**------> Doesn't work

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
alert(jQuery('#interactor #rname').attr('id'));
});
```

I am getting `undefined` as output in `alert`

When I alert the `id` id of the **first** `input` element it works fine but I am getting `undefined` output for **second** `form` element

**Snippet 2** -----> Works

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    alert(jQuery('#saveForm #rname').attr('id'));
});
```

**Snippet 1** code works for all other browsers, even for **IE11** (didn't test it for IE9 and IE10 though), but it is somehow not working for IE8

What wrong am I doing?

Comment: [`id` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) **must** be unique in the whole document. Your HTML is not valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Id must be unique for all the elements in html, but still you can try below solution:

```
jQuery('#interactor').find('#rname').attr('id')
```